# On a hard realtime OS, what happens if a process takes too long? Would programs just crash or something else?

Tags: linux, operating-systems, real-time

I've read that a realtime scheduler won't wait on a process to complete certain tasks if they take too long in order to maintain realtime capability.

The way I understand it is an OS will wait on processes even if they take too much CPU time, which may affect other processes' ability to get a chance to use the CPU. My understanding is a realtime OS won't allow this to happen, and will "cut off" these processes or suspend them, whatever if they misbehave.

My question is, what happens to a process if it takes too long?

For example, if I have some type of loop in my program that takes longer than the RTOS will allow, does the program just crash?

Comment: “For example, if I have a loop in my program that needs longer than the RTOS will allow, does the program just crash?” I almost think I know what you are talking about, but honestly I am not too sure this question can be answered without a specific example to reflect on.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Generally, the OS will wait on processes even if they take too much CPU time, which may affect other processes' ability to get a chance to use the CPU. My understanding is a realtime OS won't allow this to happen, and will "cut off" these processes or suspend them, whatever if they misbehave. I'm just trying to understand how to account for this within the program itself.

Comment: Makes sense. Edited the question to add the details in your comment to make it clearer. FWIW, this _might_ be better suited for the [Computer Science SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com) site but I’m not too sure. Just adding that info here just in case.

Comment: `a realtime OS won't allow this to happen` .. there are many RTOS OSs. of course they don't all behave the same.  Most I have worked with only support a SINGLE PROCESS that runs in a loop.  Some would argue that there is no such thing as a Linux RTOS (despite claims by projects like RTLinux).. its a matter of opinion as to what is or isn't an RTOS.  Please clarify your question to include WHAT we are actually talking about here. :)